# Anomalous "object.__init__() takes exactly one argument" from a class that inherit from another

Tags: python, class, super

I cannot understand what can cause this anomalous call of `object.__init__`
I will really appreciate a help.

Here the code. I'm including all the code, except for useless text because I don't know what cause the error

```
class IdXY(bclasses.GenStructData):
  _dtype_names=('idx', 'x', 'y');
  _dtype_nfld=len(_dtype_names);
  _dtype_formats=(str, float, float);
  _dtype_nlines=1;
  _dtype_delimiter=' ';
  _str_format="{idx:>12} {x:10f} {y:10f}";

  (idx,idn, x,y)='-',0, 0.,0.;
  withid=True;

  def _check_def(self, check_value=True):
    """Function to check if the class is defined correctly
""";
    _name_='IdXY object';
    if(self._dtype_nlines!=1): raise ValueError(_name_+": `_dtype_nlines` for this king of object can be just 1. Use the multi-lines version");
    if(not self.withid):
      if('idx' in self._dtype_names):
        if(self._dtype_names.index('idx')==0):
          self._dtype_names=self._dtype_names[1:];
          self._dtype_formats=self._dtype_formats[1:];
        else: raise SkZpipeError(_name_+"...", exclocus=_name_);
    super()._check_def(check_value=check_value); #=>bclasses.GenStructData


 ###__INIT__###
  def __init__(self, data=None, withid=None, idn=0):
    """IdXY object with 2D coordinates and eventually an ID.
""";
    _name_='IdXY object';
    if(data is None): raise ValueError(_name_+": No data to create the object");
    self.idx="-";
    if(withid is not None): self.withid=withid;

    print(self.__class__.__mro__, flush=True); #added to check
    super().__init__(data=data);
```

Then there is not important code.
Running I got:

```
> IdXY("1 2 3")
(<class 'skzpipe.parameters.classes.fileclass.basefile.IdXY'>, <class 'skzpipe.parameters.classes.bclasses.GenStructData'>, <class 'object'>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/skz/SkZ_pipeline/SkZpipe/skzpipe/parameters/classes/fileclass/basefile.py", line 562, in __init__
    super().__init__(data=data);
TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)
```

Why does the code jump to `object.__init__()` instead of executing `GenStructData.__init__()`? `GenStructData` doesn't use `super`.

Something is anomalous because:

```
> issubclass(skzpipe.parameters.classes.fileclass.basefile.IdXY,
> skzpipe.parameters.classes.bclasses.GenStructData) 
> False
```

And I defined `IdXY` as a subclass of `GenStructData`. But:

```
> skzpipe.parameters.classes.fileclass.basefile.IdXY.__mro__
> (<class 'skzpipe.parameters.classes.fileclass.basefile.IdXY'>, <class 'skzpipe.parameters.classes.bclasses.GenStructData'>, <class 'object'>)
```

EDIT:
GenStructData has a `__init__`

```
class GenStructData():
    _dtype_names=((), ());
    _dtype_datanames=None;
    _dtype_nlines=len(_dtype_names);
    _dtype_formats=((), )*_dtype_nlines;
    _dtype_nfield=tuple(len(x) for x in _dtype_names);
    _dtype_delimiter=(None,)*_dtype_nlines;
    _str_format=("", "");
    _str_len=(None, None);

  ###__INIT__###
    def _check_def(self, check_value=True):
      pass;

  def __init__(self, data=None, check_default=True, attributes=None):
    """An object from multi-lined structured data. This is not a class for direct use.""";
    _name_='GenStructData object';
    if(data is None or not isinstance(data,(str,list,tuple,GenStructData,numpy.ndarray))):
       raise TypeError(_name_+": Wrong type for `data` to create the object <{data}>".format(data=data));
    if(not self._dtype_datanames): 
      self._dtype_datanames=self._dtype_names;
    self._check_def(check_value=check_default);
    [...]
```

Comment: Are you sure `GenStructData.__init__` is named properly, and not `_init__` or `__init_` or something similar?

Comment: Your indentation is also off; the code shown would produce an error because `__init__` is not indented as far as `_check_def`. It's possible that `__init__` is defined *after* the `class` statement, rather than *in* the `class` statement (or possibly in the definition of `_check_def`), depending on what actual indentation the compiler is seeing.

Comment: The indentation is just a problem with copy-pasting the code.
The real cause was an empty predefinition of GenStructData that somehow just in this case erased the `__init__`. But also IdXY has an empty predefinition, and its `__init__` was correctly called by the subclass.

Comment: Then it sounds like your question couldn't actually reproduce your problem. Please read [mcve] for future reference.

Comment: Not completely reproducible, because part of the code was ta the beginning ans part at the and of a 700-lines file.
Anyway, partially the problem is still there (no idea why that empty class definition caused the disappearing of the `__init__` and why the subclass was not a subclass) and in my answer I included also the missing part of code.
So technically now you can reproduce everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was a no pythonic way to solve an Attribute Error caused by nested imports.

bclasses.py (where GenStructData is defined) started with

```
"""Generic classes.""";

 import os, re, math, io, copy;
 import multiprocessing as multiprc;
 import psutil, numpy;
 from sys import stdout, stderr;

 #Predefinition to avoid Attribute Error
 class GenStructData:
   pass;


 from ...exceptions import *
 from .. import basicpar as bpar
 from .. import options as _opt
 from ... import functions as funct
```

Moving `from ... import functions as funct` inside the 2 part of the code that use it (as it should be done, actually) and removing the empty definition solved the problem

> skzpipe.parameters.classes.fileclass.basefile.IdXY("1 2 3")
> 1   2.000000   3.000000

> issubclass(skzpipe.parameters.classes.fileclass.basefile.IdXY,skzpipe.parameters.classes.bclasses.GenStructData)
> True

The initial empty definition somehow messed up with the internal structure.
The anomaly is that also `IdXY` has a empty predefinition but its `__init__` was called correctly

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that GenStructData does not have an `__init__`.  In that case, it will inherit the `__init__` from `object`, hence giving you the error you see.

By the way, Python does not use a semicolon at the end of statements.  You must be used to some other language.  You should remove them; although they are not a syntax error, they are not idiomatic.

Comment: class GenStructData  has a `__init___`. 
I have included the code
Python doesn't want the ; at the end, but it can be used, even if not Pythonic ( `;` concatenate command on a single line, so it's almost like concatenate a empty line)
[link](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=semicolon)

Comment: *Please* be more careful with your reproduction. `__init___` is not the same as `__init__`, and it makes it very hard to debug your code if you won't provide something that actually reproduces your problem.